# Compulsory vs Mandatory?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, word-order

I already [google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=compulsory+vs+mandatory+meaning) but i but i cant able to understand, so if you explain for below example, it will help me to understand clearly.....

for example, If an order came from Government to people

> Education is Compulsory up to age 15.

or

> Education is Mandatory up to age 15.

what is the exact difference?

which order has the highest order priority to people?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good reference here already written...

http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-mandatory-and-vs-compulsory/